# A.s. convergence of $(M_n)^2$ in Kolmogorov's SLLN framework

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_n)n$ be IID, with finite mean µ Then, the sample mean $M_n = (X_1+...X_n) /n$ $M_n(ω) a.s. −→µ$. But what about $(M_n(ω))^2$? To me this converges to the second moment of $X$, so that we can claim that $M_n(ω) a.s. −→µ^2+(\sigma_x)^2$, **provided** that  $(\sigma_x)^2=Var[X_n]$is finite. Is this correct?

Comment: $M_n^2\to \mu^2$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

To magnify the @d.k.o. comment: If a sequence of real numbers  $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...\}$ has $x_n\rightarrow 7$, then $x_n^2\rightarrow 7^2$. So for any particular $\omega$ in the sample space for which $M_n(\omega)\rightarrow 7$, we also get $M_n(\omega)^2\rightarrow 7^2$. If almost all $\omega$ satisfy the former then almost all satisfy the latter.

Nevertheless if $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d. with finite second moment $E[X^2]$ then $\{X_n^2\}$ are i.i.d. and

$$ \frac{X_1^2+...+X_n^2}{n}\rightarrow E[X^2] \quad a.s.$$